# Equivalent of ido-mode in Intellij Idea

Tags: emacs, intellij-idea, ido

As an Emacs user, I've recently switched to using IntelliJ Idea for Java development. One thing I love about Emacs is ido-mode, where you can type C-x b and get a list of buffers to switch between. Does anyone know if this or a similar feature is available in IntelliJ? I'm using the Emacs keyset in IntelliJ and I'm aware of C-x p/n to switch between files, but I'd like to be able to just type the first few letters of the file I'm looking for, and have that file open for editing.

Comment: If you don't know it you may want to check out [eclim](http://eclim.org/) which has [an emacs interface](https://github.com/senny/emacs-eclim) and provides intelligent completion, etc. for java, so you can work in emacs while having java completion supplied by eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the default keymapping is, but you can configure them (Preferences -> Keymap) - sounds like you're looking for "Go To -> File". There's also "Recent Files" which I find very useful.

Comment: Go To File works well for this case. Not exactly the same as ido-mode, but close enough to be useful. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly (not an Emacs user):

<kbd>Control + N</kbd> on PC or <kbd>Command + N</kbd> on Mac will open the file that a particular class is in.  You'd have to provide the name of the class you want.

<kbd>Shift + Control + N</kbd> on PC or <kbd>Shift + Command + N</kbd> on Mac will open *any* file in the current project path.